# Showing that $Y\cong W$ but $X/Y\not \cong X/W$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was trying to solve the following question:

> Let $X=\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, $Y=\{0,2\}\times\{0\}$ and $W=\{0\}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. Show that $Y\cong W$ but $X/Y\not \cong X/W$.

I guess I must verify manually the Isomorphism theorems ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems)), but how should I do it without those theorems? I don't understand how to verify the statement.

Comment: Recall that if $J$ and $K$ are respective subgroups of $G$ and $H$, then $(G\times H)/(J\times K)\cong(G/J)\times(H/K)$.

Comment: There are two things you are asked to show. Which of them do you have problems with? The problem is clearly designed such that everything is small enough that you can prove things _directly_ by listing elements one by one.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have problem with both of them but lets start with the first one. I just don't understand how to approach to those questions without using those theorems?

Comment: @Baduk: The most basic and direct way to show that two groups are isomorphic is to _present an isomorphism_ between them.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes I know that. Can't think of a good isomorphism to show it

Comment: @Baduk: $Y$ and $W$ have only two elements each. This means there are just $4$ possible maps $Y\to W$. If everything else fails, try them one by one and check the conditions for being an isomorphism. (There are slicker ways to present an argument, but if one doesn't already come to mind for you, you definitely _need_ to get the practical experience with the isomorphism conditions that checking them one by one will give you).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Show that $Y\cong W\cong\Bbb Z_2$.

Secondly,  $X/Y\cong V_4=\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$, but $X/W\cong\Bbb Z_4$.

Comment: I removed all the comments to prevent unnecessary spam. I think I got it. On the second line, did you mean $X/Y\cong \mathbb{Z}_4$? if so, what good function there are for: $X/W\to \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $X/Y\to \mathbb{Z}_4$?

Comment: What are the 4 elements of those two gruops?

Comment: $X/Y=\{[(0,0)],[(0,1)],[(1,0)],[(1,1)]\}$.  Each element,  other than $[(0,0)]$, has order two.  Two elements are equal if they differ by elements of $Y$.  So $(0,0)\equiv (2,0), (0,1)\equiv (2,1),(1,0)\equiv (3,0)$ and $(1,1)\equiv (3,1)$.  $X$ has $8$ elements,  but $X/Y$ has $4$.